# Maven local install artifact does not include remote dependencies after war build

Tags: maven

I am building a target A.war, and A.war is dependent on B.jar.

B.jar has been installed locally. B.jar has some dependencies which are in the remote repository.

When A.war is built (which it says successful) none of the dependencies of B.jar are included in the final target A.war.

Comment: Does the pom info for B.jar contain the proper dependency information?

Comment: Showing the pom for both A and B would help.

Comment: Do both modules have the same parent pom?

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that `B.jar` is "installed locally". It is unclear what it means.

If `B.jar` a Maven artifact and "installed locally" means "installed in the local Maven repository", then you should take a look at `B.jar`'s `pom.xml` file and inspect the `dependencies` element. Only dependencies with the scope of `compile`, `runtime` and `test` will end up being included in `A.war`.

You can execute `mvn dependency:tree` against the `B` module and see how dependencies are calculated.

If `B.jar` is not a Maven artifact, then Maven can't really know what `B.jar`'s dependencies are. If you happen to refer to "dependencies" as "entries in the `MANIFEST.MF` file", then, well, that's not good enough for Maven.